# How to hold a List<> of opaque handles in CLI/C++?

Tags: c++, list, c++-cli, wrapper, handle

I am writing a CLI/C++ wrapper for a C-library in order to use it in C#. It must be said, I only have access to the C header file and the .lib of the C-library, not the source code.

Some of the functions I am trying to wrap are returning opaque handles, such as:

```
typedef struct SanEvent_s *SanEvent;
typedef struct SanValue_s *SanValue;
```

Returning objects of this type on the C# end seems like trouble to me, as I don't know the implementation of the struct (I tried returning the SanEvent type in the C++ wrapper but on the C# end that type is not accessible due to "protection level" or whatever it said). My plan at the moment is therefore to write some helper functions, which instead just return an integer which represents an, for example, `San Event` in a list or something. The list would be kept in the managed C++ wrapper, where I can actually manage the `San Event` type.
My problem is, I don't really know how to do this with this type of `type`.

This:

```
using System::Collections::Generic::List;
namespace Wrapper {
    public ref class Analytics
    {
    private:
        static List<SanEvent^>^ events = gcnew List<SanEvent^>();
    }
}
```

Gives me the errors: *handle to handle, pointer, or reference is not allowed*

The right hand side also complains about *expected type specifier* + the same error as above.

Can anyone give me some tips on how I could tackle this issue neatly and efficiently? My List implementation is not carved in stone, and I am open to better suggestions.

Comment: Did you tried to create managed-friendly wrapper, based on `SafeHandle`? In this wrapper on the C++/CLI side you can just store `SanEvent*` C++-style pointer and provide a set of managed-friendly functions to made necessary operations with the wrapped object. So, managed code will work with this wrapper, and the wrapper will handle the cases, when you need to pass raw C++ pinter somewhere in the C++ API.
Depending of the semantics of your C++ objects, you may also need to create factory class for such a wrappers to return the same instance of wrapper for the equals raw pointers values.

Comment: @Serg Hi. No I am unfamiliar with SafeHandle. Could you provide an example on how this would work for my case? I'm having a bit trouble following your explanation.

Comment: The easiest approach, given that you handles are struct pointers, might be to handle it all as void pointers. So have a list of void* as unsafe code in C#, pass them to a wrapper layer in C++ that also accepts void pointers, and then cast them to the correct type and performs calls down to the C library.

Comment: a pointer size is architecture-dependent.  64-bits on x64!  I would look into [IntPtr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.intptr?view=net-5.0) for anything opaque.

Answer (score 1):

Let's imagine following `SanEvent` declaration

```
struct SanEvent_s
{
    int test;
};
typedef SanEvent_s *SanEvent;
```

And following C++ API to work with such event:

```
SanEvent GetEvent()
{
    auto e = new SanEvent_s();
    e->test=42;
    return e;   
}

int UseEvent(SanEvent pEvent)
{
    return pEvent->test;
}
```

All this code contained in static library project (fully native, no CLR).

Then we have C++/CLI project to wrap this static lib.
Here we have wrapper for event itself:

```
#include "./../CppLib/SanEvent_s.h"
public ref class SanEventWrapper: Microsoft::Win32::SafeHandles::SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid
{
public:
    static SanEventWrapper^ GetWrapper()
    {
        return gcnew SanEventWrapper(GetEvent());
    }

internal:
    SanEventWrapper(SanEvent event):SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid(true)
    {
        this->e = event;
        this->handle = System::IntPtr(event);
    }

    int UseWrapper()
    {
        return ::UseEvent(this->e);
    }

protected:
    bool ReleaseHandle() override
    {
        //todo: release wrapped event
        return true;
    }

private:
    SanEvent e;
};
```

And another class which uses such a wrapper

```
public ref class SanEventConsumer
{
public:
    int ConsumeEvent(SanEventWrapper^ wrapper)
    {
        return wrapper->UseWrapper();
    }
};
```

And finally, how to use all this from C#:

```
        var wrapper = SanEventWrapper.GetWrapper();
        var consumer = new SanEventConsumer();
        var res = consumer.ConsumeEvent(wrapper);
        Console.WriteLine(res);
```

This should print `42`;

Notes:
Notes:

- this is a very simplified sample. It should be adapted ytrin accordance with semantics of 'SanEvent' struct as well as with respect of requirements of SafeHandle documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle?view=netframework-4.8 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.safehandles.safehandlezeroorminusoneisinvalid?view=netframework-4.8)
- you should decide if your wrapper will own the `SunEvent` object or not and implement `ReleaseHandle` and `Dispose` accordingly to this.
- you may consider to use another base class from this list https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.safehandles?view=netframework-4.8 instead of 'SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid' or even make direct inhernitance from `SafeHandle`.
- you can even think about dropping `SafeHandle`-related stuff at all and making the simple wrapper by your own, but it can give some surprises in connection with GC.
- depending of the semantics of the `SunEvent` you may be also need to implement factory to guarantee that you always return to the managed code the same instance of wrapper for all equals values of raw native pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something similar to what @Serg has above, but explicitly goes with the idea that you have NO IDEA in the C# world what's inside the object.

So if you have a C++/CLI library made in VS, you get this in the .h file:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <cstdint>

using namespace System;

namespace CppCliLibrary {
    public ref class Class1
    {
    public:
        static IntPtr getOpaqueInstance(int32_t argument);
        static void useOpaqueInstance(IntPtr obj);
        static void freeOpaqueInstance(IntPtr obj);
    };
}
```

Like above, using `IntPtr` to represent a pointer to "whatever".  The corresponding .cpp file is this:

```cpp
#include "pch.h"

#include "CppCliLibrary.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

namespace CppCliLibrary
{
    class OpaqueCppClass
    {
    public:
        OpaqueCppClass(int32_t arg)
            : m_int(arg) { }
        int32_t m_int;
    };
}

IntPtr CppCliLibrary::Class1::getOpaqueInstance(int32_t argument)
{
    return IntPtr(new OpaqueCppClass(argument));
}

void CppCliLibrary::Class1::useOpaqueInstance(IntPtr obj)
{
    CppCliLibrary::OpaqueCppClass* deref = reinterpret_cast<CppCliLibrary::OpaqueCppClass *>(obj.ToPointer());
    std::cout << "Contents of class are: " << deref->m_int << std::endl;
}

void CppCliLibrary::Class1::freeOpaqueInstance(IntPtr obj)
{
    CppCliLibrary::OpaqueCppClass* deref = reinterpret_cast<CppCliLibrary::OpaqueCppClass*>(obj.ToPointer());
    std::cout << "Deleting class with contents: " << deref->m_int << std::endl;
    delete deref;
}
```

Then in the C# file you have this:

```cs
namespace CsCoreConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Get an instance
            var instance = CppCliLibrary.Class1.getOpaqueInstance(52);
            // Use it
            Console.WriteLine("Got an instance we're using");
            CppCliLibrary.Class1.useOpaqueInstance(instance);
            Console.WriteLine("Freeing it");
            CppCliLibrary.Class1.freeOpaqueInstance(instance);

            // Add a bunch to a list
            List<IntPtr> opaqueInstances = new List<IntPtr>();
            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                opaqueInstances.Add(CppCliLibrary.Class1.getOpaqueInstance(i * 10));
            }

            // Use them all
            foreach(var cur in opaqueInstances)
            {
                CppCliLibrary.Class1.useOpaqueInstance(cur);
            }

            // Delete them all
            foreach (var cur in opaqueInstances)
            {
                CppCliLibrary.Class1.freeOpaqueInstance(cur);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Of course the C# project needs to reference the C++/CLI one, but you get the idea here.  The C++/CLI is a factory (nothing more, nothing less) for `IntPtr` and it can *use* it as well, because to C# it's opaque.  C# knows of nothing more than `IntPtr`.

The idea from Serg is to wrap it more, in a type-safe way.  Sure, that can work, but this is the "even more raw" variant, if you want to put it "directly" into a `List<>`